# Sad tendency to close good questions as "too broad"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen, needs-more-focus

Look at that question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791830

In my opinion it's clear and good question. User asks to describe situations when he should better use queue and deque and about advantage over using ArrayList instead queues.

Yes, this question requires detailed answer and it is little bit philosophical (like any other question about design patterns or best practices). Many questions of that kind produce active discussion with several interesting and useful opinions and a lot of up-votes. It's a kind of questions that was often asked and answered in good old days of Stackoverflow. We should force people ask only technology-troubleshooting questions.

Why we should prevent other people from adding more good use-cases for queue and deque (I can't know all off them)

It looks like:

"I see complicated question"

"Oh No, it has good answer already"

"Close. close it faster. Prevent next discussion, up-votes, all that things"

My vote is for reopen it (may be with some edit of the question by moderator)
But with my reputation I can't do anything

Don't be evil.

Be more kind. People spend a lot of forces to questions and good answers. Don't discourage them by formal reasons

Comment: So... Earn more reputation and then vote to reopen.

Comment: trying it. But questions with my good answers closes quickly. People usually don't interested by closed questions.

Comment: @paul_di Perhaps you should answer "better" questions that aren't closure candidates.

Comment: look at frequent tab at java tag. It is full of that type of questions. Yes some of them (but not all) closed now. But after weeks or months of discussion. I Don't think that we should close this kind of questions immediately. Do we want only flow of question "my program throws exception / don't work"?

Comment: 5 people voted to close.All of them did not understand it is a good question which should not be closed?

Comment: bad question for 5 expirienced moderators is not useless post for all. Moderative actions very unpredictable. And discourage people a lot of times. Now progress of this question stopped. But what the difference if it question still be open?

Comment: I'd highly recommend sticking around and seeing what SE is all about.  You'll find out very quickly it's not for open-ended, vague questions.  It's for clear, concise, *specific* questions.

Comment: This entire site is specifically designed around strict guidelines based on *formal reasons*. It's what separates us from all of the other discussion sites, chat rooms, and question sites with tons of noise and clutter and little useful information. Perhaps you need to re-take the [tour] and spend some time in the [help] to become more familiar with the site.

Comment: Just because you answer them, does not make them on topic

Comment: "Look at that question." [links to an answer] "Drrrrrrrrrrrrr"

Comment: The question you asked about is a bad question for SO because A) it's not specific, B) it encourages chatter, and C) there's no "correct" answer.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, first things first. The fact that a question has an answer doesn't mean that it should remain open. A question like:

> What is a good IDE?

Is very likely to attract *lots* of answers and should be closed (and deleted) *immediately*. Not because knowing what good IDEs are is not useful information, but because it invariably turns into an argument over whether Visual Studio is better than MonoDevelop or IntelliJ and a whole bunch of rotting links.

The linked question falls into a slightly different category, but is still a good candidate for closure. Is knowing the use cases for a FIFO or LIFO collection *useful*? Absolutely. *Answerable*? Not so much. There are probably *infinite* use cases, and we don't need a 10 page long thread of them. Questions that are a good fit for this format have answers that can fit in a couple of **paragraphs, not pages**.

Glancing over the existing answer, it seems to be a bit over the place, certainly not a full analysis of why you would or wouldn't use one (and one would no doubt be too long).

The scope of the question needs to be narrowed to work here. Perhaps something like:

> What time-complexity advantages are gained by using a linear-access collection like Queue or Deque?

<sub>Trying to be careful to not make a performance question!</sub>

Comment: I have add 3 use-cases for queue. if somebody can invent another 10 clear use-cases (common enouph) i will be agree with you. I guess it is answerable in 3-5 answers like my one

Comment: this question don't produce any kind of holy war. Just common question (rarely that it don't was asked before).

Comment: @paul_di I'm not saying it *is* going to provoke a holy war, too broad is a different category

Comment: @paul_di User Actions (as in a board game), card decks, streams, multi-step process managment, directions are 5 uses of deques/queues and it took me about two minutes to think of them. I'm sure there are *many* others.

Comment: some of them just included to my 3 as partial subcase. User actions - message sending. Streams may be too. Other should be added.. Its useful. For example i never think about card deck as queue. I is good

Comment: it is good*. I have added it

Answer (score -3):

I must admit that I have a deep, deep fondness for those questions that are broad, philosophical, subjective, etc. I get disappointed every time I see those down-voted and closed.

And I'm probably more than guilty of thinking this site should be something other than what it aims to be. People have explained it to me countless times as well as pointing me to the site guidelines about what makes a good question, and there's some disconnect there in my brain where I don't want to accept it because my ideas for the best questions aren't so in line with the standards, but they are in line with some of the most highly-upvoted questions of all time.

Because I have pages and pages of StackOverflow bookmarks as well as marked favorites to questions and answers I found really educational, and many of them are in the "too broad/subjective" category asking *"What is the best way to do this?"* with a boatload of up-votes from people interested in the same question. They somehow managed to fly under the radar of heavy moderation. Some of the mods who don't vote to close/delete those tell me they choose to keep that question around because these are old questions from another time under different standards. Well, I liked that other time with different standards. I get nostalgic thinking about it.

Cause I've been programming for a few decades now but there's plenty of things for me to learn, but I generally don't learn much from very factual questions which are just asking how to use some API or language feature, e.g. Where I still have a boatload of room to improve as a developer is not how to do things, but how to do them *better*: more efficiently, more productively, etc. And sometimes there's a question which is probably very bad by site guidelines and standards, but in spite of it an expert drawing upon many years of experience pitched in to answer it instead of voting to close it and taught me something phenomenal that changed the entire way I looked at the subject.

So yeah, I like those kinds of broad/subjective questions, because when experts decide to participate in answering them, this old dog gets to learn a few new tricks finally after sifting through endless questions that teach me nothing new at all.

And the notion of *"better"* is inherently subjective because there's endless criteria of what might make one solution better for one person and worse for another. Even SE principles like SOLID are not universally better for everyone, and we can see that with very flexible and maintainable game engines which barely adhere to them. But I can learn a lot from dissenting opinions, philosophies of developers, ideas for design. I'm often itching to see more questions that invite these lines of answers but, moreover, itching to see the answers to such questions.

The way I see it is that questions often invite either some kind of "knowledge base" answer which can easily be found in external documentation or an "experienced answer" which is drawing upon the developer's personal experience, trial and error, and maybe even "taste". The latter happen to be the most educational for me these days, but the questions that invite such answers are often the ones very likely to be closed.